# How to install vscode extension that is being developped locally from an unpacked directory

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am developping a VSCode extension that I want to try it out in the current VSCode instance, not in a new instance.

Is there a way to install the  vscode extension that is developping locally from an unpacked directory, not from a .vsix file.

In Atom editor, I can use `atom link` to do that. Is there something similar in VSCode?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/25159

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can install the extension locally with `code --install-extension` and install a locally packaged extension. I am doing this with `esbuild` and yarn:

*package.json*

```json
  "scripts": {
    "vscode:prepublish": "yarn run build:base --minify",
    "build:base": "esbuild ./src/extension.ts --bundle --outfile=out/extension.js --external:vscode --format=cjs --platform=node",
    "build": "yarn build:base --sourcemap",
    "package": "mkdirp dist && vsce package -o dist/noteberry.vsix --yarn",
    "deploy:local": "yarn package && code --install-extension dist/ext.vsix --force"
    ...
  },
```

`mkdirp` is an npm module to create folders.

**Original Post**

One easy solution without packaging as described in https://vscode-docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extensions/install-extension/ would be:

> VS Code looks for extensions under your extensions folder
> .vscode/extensions. Depending on your platform it is located:
>
> ```
> Windows %USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions
> Mac $HOME/.vscode/extensions
> Linux $HOME/.vscode/extensions
> ```
>
> If you want to load your extension or customization each time VS Code
> runs, copy your project to a new folder under .vscode/extensions.

You could write a script to delete / copy over all files.

Comment: I tried this solution but it didn't work. Is this document obsolete?  In the current document https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-marketplace , this method is no longer mentioned.

Comment: I edited the original answer. Please have a look.